# Searching a Hash Table Saved in a File

Tags: c++, search, hash

I've written a program that has created a hash table and saved it to a file. I am supposed to write a second program that allows the user to enter a key, searches the file for that key, and displays the information stored in the record matching the key that was entered.

My program has created the hash table properly and has saved it to the correct file, however, I am having trouble searching the file. When I enter a key that I know is in the hash table, I get my "this key was not found" message.

Here is my code:

My header file:

```
//prog8.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Hash {
private:
    static const int hashSize = 8;
    struct record {
        int key;
        string name;
        int code;
        double cost;
        record* next;
    };
    record* hashTable[hashSize];
public:
    Hash();
    int hash(int key);
    void addRecord(int key, string name, int code, double cost);
    int numInIndex(int index);
    void saveRecords();
    void saveRecordsInIndex(int index);
    void findRecord(int key);
};
```

My .cpp file containing the definitions for the methods:

```
//prog8.cpp
#include "prog8.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Hash::Hash() {
    for(int i = 0; i < hashSize; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = new record;
        hashTable[i]->key = 8;
        hashTable[i]->name = "blank";
        hashTable[i]->code = 0;
        hashTable[i]->cost = 0.0;
        hashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}
void Hash::addRecord(int key, string name, int code, double cost) {
    int index = hash(key);
    if(hashTable[index]->key == 8) {
        hashTable[index]->key = key;
        hashTable[index]->name = name;
        hashTable[index]->code = code;
        hashTable[index]->cost = cost;
    }
    else {
        record* ptr = hashTable[index];
        record* newRecord = new record;
        newRecord->key = key;
        newRecord->name = name;
        newRecord->code = code;
        newRecord->cost = cost;
        newRecord->next = NULL;
        while(ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = newRecord;
    }
}
int Hash::numInIndex(int index) {
    int count = 0;
    if(hashTable[index]->key == 0) {
        return count;
    }
    else {
        count++;
        record* ptr = hashTable[index];
        while(ptr->next != NULL) {
            count++;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int Hash::hash(int key) {
    int index = key % 5;
    return index;
}
void Hash::saveRecords() {
    ofstream recordsFile;
    recordsFile.open("records.dat");
    int number;
    for(int i = 0; i < hashSize; i++) {
        number = numInIndex(i);
        recordsFile << "-------------\n";
        recordsFile << "Index = " << i << endl;
        recordsFile << hashTable[i]->key << endl;
        recordsFile << hashTable[i]->name << endl;
        recordsFile << hashTable[i]->code << endl;
        recordsFile << hashTable[i]->cost << endl;
        recordsFile << "Number of items in index = " << number << endl;
        recordsFile << "-------------\n";
    }
}
void Hash::saveRecordsInIndex(int index) {
    ofstream recordsFile;
    recordsFile.open("records.dat");    
    record* ptr = hashTable[index];
    if(ptr->key == 0) {
        cout << "Index " << index << " is empty";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Index " << index << " contains the following records:\n";
        while(ptr != NULL) {
            recordsFile << "--------------\n";
            recordsFile << ptr->key << endl;
            recordsFile << "--------------\n";
            ptr = ptr->next;
            //index++;
        }
    }
}
void Hash::findRecord(int key) {
    ifstream recordsFile;
    recordsFile.open("records.dat");
    if(!recordsFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }
    int index = hash(key);
    bool wasFound = false;
    record* ptr = hashTable[index];
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(ptr->key == key) {
            wasFound = true;
            key = ptr->key;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    if(wasFound == true) {
        cout << key;
    }
    else {
        cout << "There was no record matching the key " << key << " found."
        << endl;
    }
    recordsFile.close();
}
```

My first main file:

```
//prog8main.cpp
#include "prog8.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream file;
    file.open("prog8.dat");
    if(!file.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }
    int index;
    int key;
    string name;
    int code;
    double cost;
    Hash hashObj;
    if(key != 8) {
        while(file >> key && file >> name && file >> code && file >> cost) {
            hashObj.addRecord(key, name, code, cost);
            hashObj.saveRecords();
            //hashObj.saveRecordsInIndex(index);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

And my main file to search the output file:

```
//prog8search.cpp
#include "prog8.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int key;
    Hash hashObj;
    cout << "Please enter a key ";
    cin >> key;
    hashObj.Hash::findRecord(key);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of the output I'm getting, complete with the records.dat file that was created:

```
[cs331129@cs ~]$ g++ -o prog8 prog8.cpp prog8main.cpp
[cs331129@cs ~]$ prog8
[cs331129@cs ~]$ cat records.dat
-------------
Index = 0
12345
Item06
45
14.2
Number of items in index = 2
-------------
-------------
Index = 1
34186
Item25
18
17.75
Number of items in index = 2
-------------
-------------
Index = 2
12382
Item09
62
41.37
Number of items in index = 3
-------------
-------------
Index = 3
8
blank
0
0
Number of items in index = 1
-------------
-------------
Index = 4
12434
Item04
21
17.3
Number of items in index = 1
-------------
-------------
Index = 5
8
blank
0
0
Number of items in index = 1
-------------
-------------
Index = 6
8
blank
0
0
Number of items in index = 1
-------------
-------------
Index = 7
8
blank
0
0
Number of items in index = 1
-------------
[cs331129@cs ~]$ g++ -o prog8search prog8.cpp prog8search.cpp
[cs331129@cs ~]$ prog8search
Please enter a key 12345
There was no record matching the key 12345 found.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by being considerably more succinct in your storage choice. You're saving an arguably pointless amount of data to you .dat file that does *nothing* but make *reading* the file more difficult.

Comment: Ok, but for now do you have any ideas as to how I can search what I've already have there?

Comment: Your `findRecord` opens a file but doesn't read anything from it, so your table is empty. You probably want to write "records.dat" in a more machine-readable format. Also, reading the file each time you want to search through it is going to be extremely inefficient. Separate loading and searching in different functions.

Comment: Also, the professor that suggested implementing a "hash table" as a singly-linked list can be summarily be fired, thank you very much.

Comment: (prog08.h and cs331129@cs are tell-tale signs and making me weep for the state of CS education).

Comment: I only have to make it through finals and then I'll be changing majors ha. And yes, I don't really have anything nice to say about this professor.

Comment: Well, that dodges the question. DId _he_ suggest a singly linked list? Or ... did you just try to copy code from an earlier assignment :)

Comment: I have no idea. Part of this was from an earlier assignment, where we just had to create a hash table. This assignment was mainly supposed to just build off of that one and use external hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream recordsFile;
recordsFile.open("records.dat");
if(!recordsFile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
}
```

Here you opened the file.

Yet you **read nothing** ever.

So when you do stuff like

```
record* ptr = hashTable[index];
```

The table will by definition be empty since you still have to read anything from the records.dat file.

Remember: *Programming is not magic. It may seem like that at first, but nothing ever happens unless the code was written (by anyone at all, not necessarily you)*

Comment: Not sure what I need to do to read it in properly? I tried doing it basically like I did the input file to create the table, but when I run it that way I am asked to enter a key and then once I do the program exits without displaying anything.

Comment: That's a symptom of not doing input validation. Here's a start: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38b286548e0ae376)** I've specifically not tried to understand how this is supposed to be a hash table (I think you might be using keys as hashes in some places, but that's up to you)

Answer (score 2):

I see a number of issues with your code:

1. Your hash index size is 8? So why are you modding by 5?  That means cells 5, 6 and 7 will always be empty as they will be redirected to 0, 1 and 2.
2. Why in main() are you outputting after every record read? Why not do that at the end? (If you didn't insist on that awful bracing style it would be clearer what you are doing, although others will disagree with me on the style issue).
3. Your code of course leaks, isn't const-correct and could do in general with better structuring.
4. What does "findRecord" do with the input file? I can't see it reading it.
5. Why are you doing checks on key==0? Isn't that a valid key?

Comment: I had to use the hash function I was given as part of the instructions which was the value of the key mod 5. Other than that, yes I know I suck at this which is why I'm changing majors effective next semester. My mind just doesn't work this way, I can read about all this stuff all day and it just doesn't click. So I don't really have a response to the second and third issues.

Comment: People like me who work in the industry professionally are likely to know a lot more about writing good code than your professors. You just looked surprised that cells 5, 6 and 7 were empty when they are always going to be. What is this comparison with 0 doing here though:
nt Hash::numInIndex(int index) {
    int count = 0;
    if(hashTable[index]->key == 0) {
        return count;

Comment: Oh no doubt, I have the utmost respect for what y'all do. No I kind of realized when I saw it was going to be modded by 5 rather than the table size which is usually the case, that it wasn't going to be using those last few spaces. I think he just wanted to insure that we'd get collisions that we'd have to deal with. And that was a typo, it was supposed to be an 8 rather than a 0. We sere supposed to fill the file with "dummy records" with the key being the first number in the file which was 8, so that's where that comes from.

Comment: Oh and the findRecord method is only supposed to be looking in the output file

Comment: @CashCow yup. I've tried to salvage some of these points but got lost in the end (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38b286548e0ae376))